# Rails system test drivers can I still use rack_test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rack-test

Rails system tests use Capybara. Capybara uses `rack_test` driver by default, while System tests uses `selenium` by default.

Capybara Drivers:

- [rack_test](https://github.com/rack/rack-test) is a small ruby api which works with [Rack](https://github.com/rack/rack) (a web stack underlying nearly all Ruby web frameworks) - it is unaware of javascript
- [selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium) a driver to manage [libraries enabling web browser automation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium) - it is aware of Javascript as it actually automating a physical web-browser.

I want to know why these were chosen and what are sensible choices for a Rails programmer writing System tests.

Comment: Selenium is browser automation software and is used to test applications by driving an actual browser (headless or not). rack_test just simulates a browser by crawling HTML with a parser. `rack_test` thus cannot test be used to test JavaScript or any real browser behavior. And of course `rack_test` is faster. Its only doing 1/100th of the job that an actual browser does.

Comment: And yes there are edge cases where an actual browser and rack test will differ even when you're not testing javascript so your conclusions are kind of nonsensical. Use rack_test if the trade-off is worth it but don't delude yourself that they are in any way equatable.

Comment: I think the title was wrong. It gave the impression that it was a run off between the two. When it was really "can I _still_ use rack_test in system tests" The original conclusion gave a lukewarm "If your system test isn't using Javascript you may consider using rack_test instead. " - which I would hope didn't lead people to the conclusion the drivers were the same - however, I have now emphasized that they are different. I hope that addresses your issues?

Answer (score 0):

System tests run using Capybara. Capybara use drivers to complete the testing. Capybara drivers can be defined as:

> The driver is the part of Capybara that actually manages a web page
>   as a series of DOM elements - Rails 5 Test Prescriptions - Noel Rappin.

[Capybara uses by default a rack_test driver, a faster but JavaScript unaware version.](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#selecting-the-driver) while [Rails system tests uses by default, a slower but Javascript aware version, selenium](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/testing.html#system-testing) - [think this code sets the Rails default.](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/system_test_case.rb#L121)

I wanted to know the reasons for the default and if I could still be using `rack_test`. I found a quote from the original PR:

> I chose the Selenium driver as default because the
>   purpose of adding system testing to Rails is for the initial setup to
>   be absolutely zero. Capybara does that through their default, Rack
>   Test, but it's not really a useful demonstration of the merits of
>   system testing since it doesn't support JavaScript testing.
>   [Comment in PR from Eileen codes](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/26703#issuecomment-251649333)

So there's no technical reason to choose Selenium vs Rack. Selenium was chosen as it was a fuller functioned low configuration default.

Rack test is limited it was described as:

> If you don't want a full browser - if you just want to assert on HTML
>   instead of just executing Javascript ... What rack test does is
>   basically fakes out communication between a real browser with a fake
>   one which Capybara can use to parse the response without making a web
>   request at all. You can make assertions about what the page contains.
>
> [Rails conf 2018 - Sam Phippen](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JD-28Oi7fxI&t=17m44s)

If your system test isn't using Javascript you may consider using `rack_test` instead. However, it's a trade off - rack will be faster because it doesn't know about Javascript but it can't replace the complexity of a physical browser.